# Case classes, pattern matching and curried constructors in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, currying, case-class

They don't seem to mix that well:

```
abstract class A
case class B (var a: Int)(var b: String) extends A
case class C extends A
```

The following will not work:

```
B(1)("1") match {
  case B(a)(b) => print("B")
  case C() => print("C")
}
```

The problem is that pattern matching and curried arguments do not seem to work. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
def m(a: A) = a match {
  case b: B => print("B")
  case c: C => print("C")
}
```

I'm only asking because you didn't ask for more functionality than this.

**EDIT**

This could help:

```
object Dog {
   def apply(name: String)(size: Int) = new Dog(name)(size)
   def unapply(dog: Dog) = Some(dog.name, dog.size)
}
class Dog(val name: String)(var size: Int)
```

Now you can create dogs either like this:

```
new Dog("Snoopy")(10)
```

or like this:

```
Dog("Snoopy")(10)
```

But when you pattern match on dogs the constructor pattern is **not** curried.

```
Dog("Snoopy")(10) match {
   case Dog(a, b) => // do sth with a or b
}
```

Comment: Your first example would work, but I would not be able to access B.a and B.b in the case statement without doing some ugly typecasting. Also, in your edit, I'm not sure I understand why the constructor pattern is not curried. Is it because unapply?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea why it works. I stumbled over it through trial and error. It is most certainly mentioned somewhere in the Scala specification. You might wanna look it up if it's relevant in your case.

Comment: Yes, the pattern you use in a case statement is the one given by the result of the unapply function. It can never be curried. The corresponding section in the scala specification is the §8.1.8

Comment: Indeed, it is the unapply function. Here is a more readable resource, if you don;t want to read the specs: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112

Answer (score 14):

If you look at the signature of the unapply function created for the class B, you will see that it is: `unapply(x$0: Q): Option[Int]`. Thus, the unapply function works with the first range of parameter of the case classes.

It is confirmed by the scala specification (§5.3.2):

> The formal parameters in the **ﬁrst parameter section** of a case class
>   are called elements; they are treated specially. First, the value of
>   such a parameter can be extracted as a ﬁeld of a constructor pattern.

It claims clearly tha only the first parameter section is available through the extractor.

Several workarounds:

- uncurry your parameters
- use a pattern matching with guard if you want to test the 2 values: `case x@B(3) if x.b == "bazinga" => ...`
- use a normal class and define your own companion object with your own apply / unapply

Answer (score 2):

You could use a normal case class and just define a factory method with more than one parameter list.

Comment: May be we can add that the factory method cannot be caleed `apply` if it is declared in the companion object (since it will have the same erasure as the one declared thanks to the case class).